# A simple question in complex analysis

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is the contour integral in upper plane different from the lower plane in this case?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk\frac{1}{(k-a)(k+a)(p-k-b)(p-k+b)}$

where $\text{Im }a$ and $\text{Im }b$ are negative and $p$ is real. Besides, $\text{Re }a$, $\text{Re }b$, and $p$ are positive.

The the poles in complex plane are shown below:
[image]

Comment: Did you calculate the residue at each pole?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Yes, I've calculated the residue at each pole. Since I encounter this question in the loop momentum integration, thus I post here.

Comment: If I do the contour integral in the upper plane, I will get 
$-2\pi i \left(\frac{1}{2a[(p-a)^2-b^2]}-\frac{1}{2b[(p+b)^2-a^2]}\right)$.
But if I integrate in the lower plane, I will get $-2\pi i \left(\frac{1}{2a[(p+a)^2-b^2]}-\frac{1}{2b[(p-b)^2-a^2]}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand vanishes sufficiently fast at large $|k|$ that you can close the contour in either the upper or the lower half-plane. You will get the same answer in either case. In other words, the sum of the residues at the four poles will be  zero. Why don't you check that this is indeed true?

Note added: For a general case
$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}
$$
the residue sum is 
$$
\frac 1{(a - b) (a - c) (a - d)} + \frac{1}{(b - a) (b - c) (b - d)} + 
 \frac{1}{(c - a) (c - b) (c - d)} + \frac 1{(d - a) (d - b) (d - c)}
$$
A somewhat  tedious calculation shows that this sum is zero. A quicker way to see that this must be true is to consider the   partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}=\frac{A}{x-a}+ \frac{B}{x-b}+\frac{C}{x-c}+\frac{D}{x-d}
$$
and take the large $x$ limit. Then the LHS is $1/x^4+ O(x^{-5})$ while 
$$
RHS= \frac{A+B+C+D} x+ O(x^{-2})
$$
Agreement requires $A+B+C+D=0$ togther with similar, but  non-trivial-looking, quadratic and cubic relations on the $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: the four residues are $\frac{1}{2a[(p-a)^2-b^2]}$, $-\frac{1}{2b[(p+b)^2-a^2]}$, $-\frac{1}{2a[(p+a)^2-b^2]}$, and $\frac{1}{2b[(p-b)^2-a^2]}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. I get these residues by just putting a into the other three denominators (k+a), (p-k-b), (p-k+b). and so do the other three poles p+b, -a, p-b (since each pole is a simple pole). What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer. I've found that the residues exactly cancel each others.